# How to execute nested commands in Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby

I want to execute nested commands using ruby. E.g.,

```
ls $(cat file_name.txt)
```

In the command above, `file_name.txt` is the file name I want to search for. But due to the `$` character, it does not work.

Comment: you may want to add a little detail as to what code you have tried, and the exact error

Comment: is this javascript? is it ruby? is it bash? what is that?

Comment: Running the command(s) in a subshell should work, e.g. via [`\`...\``](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if it's ruby use the exec method or backticks:

```
exec("ls $(cat file_name.txt)")
`ls $(cat file_name.txt)`
```